# Flex 4 Skin:Specifying state for an attribute in script

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, state, skin

I'm trying to create a button skin, where i can set fillColors like in a Flex 3 button, using CSS.
It was easy to set the color of the gradients, by reading them from the CSS:
adding a few lines in updateDisplayList:  fillGradient1.color = fillColors[0]; ...

How can i set the colors for the other states, from script? 
I tried adding fillGradient1.color.down = fillColors[2] and it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a short/fast

read http://unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2009/07/02/flex-4-spark-skinning/

at the bottom of article you'll find CSS usage, so call styles for different states - different.

And yes you are not able to get colors from style by .state, but you could use it in skin like:

`<local:childComponent styleName.state="optional" .../>`